# C fprintf encoded string skipping

Tags: c, scanf, printf

Here is a snippet of a code, where I print strings with whitespaces from a text into another txt file. I have a codelist, I have to switch particular strings with the correct code. Codes are in an array. I cant make the encode function work. Fprintf prints the code *followed by* the base string. I want to skip these strings. I only need the codes to get printed. Where do I miss something?

```
int m;
file = fopen("input.txt", "r" );
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF ) {        
    for (m=0; m<j; m++) {                           
        if (strcmp(word, particularwords[m]) == 0) {     
            fprintf(outfile, "%s ", code[m]);
            continue;                     
        }
    }
fprintf(outfile, "%s ", word);
}
```

Comment: Don't use (`f`)`scanf` to read strings (but if you really have to, specify the length). Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Do your 'codes' contain additional `%` signs?

Comment: nah it contains only lowcase chars from the english alphabet, but nvm, already solved!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the continue is the problem.

it continue the for loop not the while.

This is what I think should be:

```
int m;
file = fopen("input.txt", "r" );
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF ) {        
    for (m=0; m<j; m++) {                           
        if (strcmp(word, particularwords[m]) == 0) {     
            fprintf(outfile, "%s ", code[m]);
            break; //for                     
        }
    }
    if(m==j){ //word not found!
       fprintf(outfile, "%s ", word);
    }
}
```